# Permission denied while FileOutputStream from external storage but read in internal storage

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, android-file, android-external-storage

While moving files from external storage permission denied error on FileOutputStream from external storage path but it works on internal storage path.

I have tried this and my permisson is granted for Read & Write.

```
File yourFile = new File(outputPath+"/"+file.getName());
if(!yourFile.exists()) { yourFile.createNewFile(); }
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false);
```

Here is my code: Path is just a string for internal & external too. 
String OutputInternal = "/storage/emulated/0/test1/testing"
String OutputExternal = "/storage/1A7D-0850/test1/testing"

```
private void moveFile(File file, String outputPath) {

        if (file != null && !outputPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {

                //create output directory if it doesn't exist
                File dir = new File(outputPath);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }


                in = new FileInputStream(file); 
                out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath+"/"+file.getName());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                in.close();
                in = null;

                // write the output file
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;

                file.delete();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

It works when path is from internal storage but when i select external path it shows error on fileOutputStream (Permission Denied)

Comment: Perhaps you did not request your runtime permissions. Perhaps you are using Android 10+, in which case you do not have filesystem-level access to external storage.

Comment: Actually, I think they're confusing external storage with removable storage. Check the `OutputInternal` and `OutputExternal` values.

Comment: I am using Android minSdk 21 and target Sdk 28, and grant permission on runtime for read/write external storage.

Comment: yes external storage has removable storage path and output internal has internal storage path from both path read files but when i move file from external storage FileOutputStream exception to permission denied.

Comment: the way you are accessing files is already legacy, take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: Can you tell me what i have mistaken, I did not understand.